# How do I get the old sticky notes back?

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

Windows 10 did one of those updates where you sit down at your PC and are welcomed with "Hi!", "We restarted your computer".

And of course they messed with my sticky notes. They seem to be 'metro' updated and it wouldn't be a Windows update unless they removed functionality. In addition to removing • bulleted lists, **bold**, *italics*, and <strike>strikethrough</strike> the font was changed from Segoe Print to a sans serif one (after 4 years it grows on you).

Here's an image of the updated version:

[image]

Is there any way I can get the old sticky notes back?

Comment: [Of course they added spell check..](https://vgy.me/yXh6iU.png)

Comment: In case someone (like me) wants to migrate his notes to new StickyNote : [import-sticky-notes-windows-7-to-10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/import-sticky-notes-windows-7-to-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried this but here's a possible solution:
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/get-classic-sticky-notes-windows-10-anniversary/

> If you’re not going to use the new features (Cortana integration, Ink)
>   of the modern Sticky Notes app, you can get the classic desktop
>   version (StickNot.exe) after upgrading to the Windows 10 anniversary
>   update (v1607) build.
>
> If the C:\Windows.old…Windows\System32 directory is still intact,
>   simply copy “StikyNot.exe” to your Windows\System32 folder and create
>   a shortcut to it on your desktop. Also, make sure you copy
>   StikyNot.exe.mui file from “Windows\System32\en-US” folder (for
>   English language version of Windows), and place it in the same path in
>   the target computer. The program still works in Windows 10 version
>   1607.
>
> Another option would be to obtain the ISO image of 10586.494
>   (preferably) and extract the two files StikyNot.exe and
>   StikyNot.exe.mui using 7-Zip or similar archive utility.
>
> If none of those options are feasible, you may download it from this
>   site.

Comment: I don't have any `Windows.old`, but downloading the files provided on that site do indeed work.

Comment: This didn't work for me. If you do not have sntsearch.dll, then you will not be able to close sticky notes or change their colors.

Comment: Stopped working after December 2018 feature update to Windows 10 Home 1809 (OS build 17763.194). I copied it into the System32 folder (including the MUI file to the en-US folder) as usual after bigger update, but it won't run. The task is starting for a second or two, either displaying name Sticky Notes when MUI file is present, or no name at all f I delete it, there's no icon and it silently ends without ever showing anything. Any ideas how to fix it?

I tried downloading SNTSearch.dll, doesn't help.

Comment: Opened another question: https://superuser.com/q/1386589/458487 Apparently there are some other DLLs or resources missing, it runs from System32 in the Windows.old folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Update (2018):** The link for the download appears to be fixed!

---

Since the other solution didn't work for me (if you do not have sntsearch.dll, then you will not be able to close sticky notes or change their colors), I will share what I found that worked:

> 1. Go to **C:\** and find a folder called **Windows.old** It should have been created after the update.
> 2. Go to **C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32** find and copy these two files:
>
>    - StikyNot.exe
>    - SNTSearch.dll
> 3. Go to **C:\Windows\System32** and paste the two files you just copied.
> 4. Go to **C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32\en-US** find and copy these two files:
>
>    - sntsearch.dll.mui
>    - StikyNot.exe.mui
>    - The folder en-US will vary depending on your system language, for instance: es-ES for spanish.
> 5. Go to **C:\Windows\System32\en-US** and paste the two files you just copied.
> 6. Now let's add Sticky Notes back to the start menu where it used to be. Go to **C:\Windows\System32** and find **StikyNot.exe** then right click on it, on the menu that pops up, click on **Send To>Desktop (create shortcut)**
> 7. Go to your desktop, the Sticky Notes shortcut should be there. Rename it to whatever you want.
> 8. Go to **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories** (You will need to enable show hidden files in order to find this path. Here a tutorial on how to do it:
>      https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10.html)
> 9. Copy the shortcut from the desktop and paste it here.
> 10. Done! Now the sticky notes should be in the Start Menu under **Windows Accessories**, and you can also find it by using the Start Menu search box
>
> **Note:** If for whatever reason you don't have the Windows.old folder, you can download the files from this tutorial at step 3: http://www.techflute.com/how-to-add-sticky-notes-to-windows-server-2012/

- [Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94a04847-690f-4984-a0f9-12e0e5150ab1/sticky-notes-functionality-broken-by-windows-10-update?forum=win10itproapps)

---

#### Download

For your convenience, here is a direct link to the mentioned download: http://techflute.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/StickyNotes(TechFlute.com).rar

You will need to have [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) or some other program that can extract a .rar file.