# How to get old Sticky Notes back after December 2018 update to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes, windows-10-v1809

I used for years this solution: https://superuser.com/a/1173332/458487 linking to https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/get-classic-sticky-notes-windows-10-anniversary/

After December 2018 "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1809", it no longer works, tested on both Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional (Home OS build 17763.194).

I copied the old stikynot exe and mui files into the System32 folder (including the MUI file to the en-US folder) as usual after bigger update, but it won't run. The task is starting for a second or two, either displaying name Sticky Notes when MUI file is present, or no name at all f I delete it, there's no icon and it silently ends without ever showing anything. Any ideas how to fix it?

I tried downloading SNTSearch.dll, doesn't help.

Thank you very much! I don't want to use the obnoxious Metro-styled new Sticky Notes - either I repair this, or will find an alternative. But I grew used to the look and ease of use.

---

EDIT: On other machine I haven't purged the Windows.old folder yet, and when I run it from System32 there, it starts. So we're probably missing some other DLL. Any idea how to find out which? Are there any logs anywhere? I'm not that familiar with debugging under Windows unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run old Sticky Note in Windows 10 Version 1809 aka. October 2018 Update, `StikyNot.exe` needs a compatible **DUI70.DLL** file (Windows DirectUI Engine). A fair bit of warning, there are many websites which provide DLL files (Dynamic Link Library) for free. DO NOT download them because they may contain harmful malwares.

There are [many ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+old+windows+10+iso+files) to download old Windows 10 ISO files. Here I have choose a tool [from HeiDoc.net](https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/67-microsoft-windows-and-office-iso-download-tool) which uses official Microsoft link to download ISO files. For this procedure, I have used two Windows 10 versions --

- [Version 1511 (November Update)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1511_(November_Update)) for `StikyNot.exe` and `StikyNot.exe.mui`
- [Version 1803 (April 2018 Update)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Version_1803_(April_2018_Update)) for `DUI70.DLL` and `DUI70.dll.mui`

Extract those files from their ISO files respectively. Here are the list of what we need:

```
Win10_1511_English_x64.iso
|
+-- sources
    |
    +-- install.wim
        |
        +-- Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe
        +-- Windows\System32\en-US\StikyNot.exe.mui

Win10_1803_English_x64.iso
|
+-- sources
    |
    +-- install.wim
        |
        +-- Windows\System32\DUI70.dll
        +-- Windows\System32\en-US\DUI70.dll.mui
```

The `en-US` folder may change according to the main locale of that ISO file, for example, `en-GB` for UK English, `zh-CN` for simplified Chinese etc. Copy those above four files in any folder like this:

```
MyFolder
|
+-- StikyNot.exe
+-- DUI70.dll
|
+-- en-US
    |
    +-- StikyNot.exe.mui
    +-- DUI70.dll.mui
```

Alternatively, both files can be copied from Windows 7 ISO file. So how did I find the dependency of `DUI70.dll`? Answer, with [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) tool (open-source and free) and some trial 'n error. Open the `StikyNot.exe` in that tool. It will show many functions are imported from `DUI70.dll` library. The other imported functions are from System32 libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth reply! However, in my system, the files dui70.dll and dui70.dll.mui are present both in Windows.old and the current version. They are different - old dui70.dll has 1 719 808 bytes (created Jun 6, 18, 20:43, md5 923706cce2eb713fa7cc04db93c52da3) and the new one has 1 761 280 bytes and is from Sep 15, 18, 09:28 (44017d29603b61caacfe78161070403f). Can't delete/overwrite the new one even as an administrator - apparently it's in use. Any other clues? Do you want a list of files in my System32?

Comment: For some reason I was stuck trying to make it work in the live System32 folder, while the obvious solution is to put it elsewhere (like `C:\Program Files (x86)\stikynot`). So, the files working for me, pulled from an older version of the system (don't need anything else in the folder): `b2e22260e4238371b90a1ad8d85804d1` *dui70.dll `42e7a1e58b1708de50db56dfbe061ab3` *StikyNot.exe `53c978bed543b4716925f6a361887fda` *en-US\dui70.dll.mui `a4ba35f4eb39a76e3067d840258bcd94` *en-US\StikyNot.exe.mui

**Thanks, @Biswapriyo!**