# Windows 10 Getting Sticky Notes Back Using Hard Drive Dock

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

So my main system failed me on Christmas ironically. Anyways, I am certain its the motherboard, which means I need to change the motherboard and it won't boot into windows because of a hardware change most likely. So I plugged in my ssd into a hard drive dock and got the ssd to show on my other system. I got everything off of the ssd onto another drive, except I can't find where my sticky note file is. I looked online and online said it would be either in appdata/Microsoft/roaming or it would be in the packages folder. I did find where it has the name of sticky notes but my file isn't there. So the 2 locations they said online didn't have my sticky notes. I really need it. I tried calling up Microsoft support and this was to advance for them as they were not trained in data apparently. I also seen this thread:

[How do I get the old sticky notes back?](https://superuser.com/questions/1173331/how-do-i-get-the-old-sticky-notes-back)

This thread didn't work for me as StikyNot.exe and SNTSearch.dll isn't in system32. I feel like I have tried every thing I can and seen on google to no avail. So you guys are my last resort, else I am just done for I guess. So please help anyone out there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hardware change is no reason for windows to not boot. The only thing that may happen is that windows decides your key is invalid and makes your copy of windows a trial version. You probably can activate it again though. Running in windows should allow you to expor the sticky notes from the notes app itself.

Comment: Also, Sticky Notes is an app, so it is located in a secured folder in the program files folder or your user folder. I don't know exactly where it is located but the folders are protected because changing stuff breaks the app and Microsoft wants to prevent that. Also because they are supposed to be cross platform compatible.

Comment: Omg, I got it back. About your comments, I am fairly certain windows won't boot with a motherboard change, I forgot to mention that I am not changing it out to the same model of motherboard, I am changing to a completely different make and model and manufacture. Anyways, I managed to solve my problem and am going to post my own solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can boot as long as it is on the same sata port as before. It would not be the first time I did this in order to get foreign software backupped that would not work by just copying files. In worst cases, you need to fix the boot records, but the motherboard is just some hardware. Windows does not require it to be the same, it just must work like it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my own problem as a you tube video showed the answer. So to get back your sticky note from a drive, go to C:Users\your name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Microsoftstickynotes\LocalState

Then locate a file named:"plum.sqlite" and open that as a notepad document. Don't change anything inside here but rather just copy. Anyways, scroll through and find your information and just copy and past to a destination of your choice.

Comment: You can keep the formatting by exiting sticky notes and copying the plum.sqlite file here: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState Don't overwrite anything new, though.